# SQL Server HashBytes

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

Can you unhash a value that you have stored in the DB?

So if I generate and store a value like this

```
SELECT HashBytes('MD5', 'HelloWorld')
```

Can I use a function to unhash it so that I can get the original value backout?

Thanks,

S

Comment: No. Hashes are by definition, one-way. Also, you realise MD5 is broken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately not. If you are trying to check if a password or pass phrase is correct, you would only be able to encrypt what you've received, and then compare the two results. If they differ, then obviously the wrong information has been passed in.

Comment: Ah dang it. Someone beat me to it.

Comment: Thanks fortheworld I figured that was the only approach.

Answer (score 2):

No. [Cryptographic hashes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) are by definition one way.

Comment: Thanks Remus I figured as much.  Thanks for the info.